# Azure AD authentication from username and password

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a WPF app that will run outside of our network on client computers. I would like to prompt users for a username and password, and then test that username and password against our Azure AD Authentication. If passed the user will use the token to access our BLOB storage.

I cannot get any c# code that will do the above, can anyone please point me in the correct direction here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Identity.Client` from Nuget for Azure AD auth.
for more info :https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop

Also this link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop